# Word for "already know but may not know the terminology"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say a sentence like: "The notion of physical phases is a concept everyone *knows but many may not be aware of the terminology* "phase". Phase just means solid, liquid or gas."

Is there a word that captures the meaning of the italics?

Comment: The word you're looking for aside, the sentence in your question is ungrammatical. One way of fixing it is to add *many* after *but*.

Comment: Not an issue with English but a minor point of science: *phase* also includes plasma (e.g. the Sun, lightning) and other more unusual states such as Bose-Einstein condensate - see [states of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter).

Comment: Something like _intuitively understands_ or _has an intuitive grasp of_ gets you most of the way there but: 1. They're phrases, not single words and this is a _single-word-request_. 2. The idea of not knowing the terminology isn't where the emphasis is and to what extent it is there it is only by implication.

Comment: How can there be a single word for such a long phrase? What’s wrong with the sentence as it is? Are you actually looking for a more elegant rewording? E.g, *It is common knowledge that matter can occur in different states, solid, liquid or gaseous. But many people are not aware of the technical term for this concept: phases.* What exactly is it you want?

Comment: @Chappo just to clarify that I do know this but I used this simplification for the question so it's more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say **in layman's terms** or **"superficially"**

- "The notion of physical phases is a concept everyone knows "in layman's terms/superficially."

> [**layman's terms**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/layman's%20terms) - simple language that anyone can understand.
>
> [**superficial**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superficially) -  superficial implies a concern only with surface aspects or obvious features: a superficial analysis of the problem.
>
> Examples from the web:
>
> "... problems labeled either **in layman's terms** (such as stomach upset and sore throat) or in medical terms (such as gastroenteritis and tonsillitis)"
>
> "This fourth edition explains more fully the principles of coaching **in layman's terms** and illustrates them with simple analogies"
>
> "Can the concept of time travel be explained **in layman's terms**?"
>
> ""We always say, very **superficially**, “That's your ego,” but we have no idea what the ego really is.""
>
> "There are many conditions that may **superficially** mimic autism but may have a completely different set of etiologies."

Comment: I just used your wording in a paper submission, thanks!

Comment: @Daochen Why not mark it as the solution?